# Liferay 7 , Abstract and tags of web content are not added as meta description and keywords

Tags: seo, liferay, liferay-7, web-content

In liferay 6.2 when I create web content or blog , I add Abstract and tag for categorization .

In asset publisher when I click on view more for full content then in page this abstract is added as meta description and tag is added as meta keywords .

But in liferay 7 this is not happening . I am not able to find that whether this feature has been removed in liferay 7 or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that we don't have that feature on Liferay 7. I wrote several comments on their issues forum but it hasn't been fixed or changed.

I will release a blog post about it this week and I hope they will take care about it in future releases.

Regards